# lua script fails with module not found

Tags: lua

I am running a lua script.

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

require("posix")
require("math")
require("os")
-- ...
```

It fails with following error:

```
xctest7b # lua attack.lua
lua: attack.lua:3: module 'posix' not found:
        no field package.preload['posix']
        no file './posix.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/posix.lua'
        no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/posix/init.lua'
        no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/posix.lua'
        no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/posix/init.lua'
        no file './posix.so'
        no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/posix.so'
        no file '/usr/lib64/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        attack.lua:3: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

I have already installed both luarocks and luaposix.  Install of luaposix completes with:

```
luaposix 33.3.1-1 is now built and installed in /usr/local
```

Any tips on what I really need to install?

Paths:

```
xctest7b # lua -e "print(package.cpath)"
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so;./?.so

xctest7b # lua -e "print(package.path)"
/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/posix;/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua;

xctest7b # find /usr/local -name posix
/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/posix
```

Comment: `I am running a lua script.` - What script? At least post the first few lines of it. (Edit the question to do this).

Comment: Lua told you exactly where it looked for the posix module. None of those file paths starts with `/usr/local`. It seems you need to update your `LUA_PATH` and/or `LUA_CPATH` environment variables.

Comment: Try `require "luarocks.loader"` before requiring the posix module. Check out [Using LuaRocks](https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/wiki/Using-LuaRocks)

Comment: @Adam: It is likely that the luarocks.loader module is installed somewhere in `/usr/local` as well ...

Comment: @siffiejoe  paths:                                                                                            xctest7b # lua -e "print(package.cpath)"
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/loadall.so;./?.so

xctest7b # lua -e "print(package.path)"
/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/posix;/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?.lua;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.3/?/init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua;

xctest7b # find /usr/local -name posix
/usr/local/share/lua/5.3/posix

Comment: @user5916060: It seems that there are two different Lua interpreters involved: The first one thinks it's Lua 5.1, while the second is probably Lua 5.3. `require`ing luaposix should work for the second interpreter with the settings you posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CentOS or similar, try to do:

```
sudo yum install lua-posix
```

Otherwise, if you are using Debian/Ubuntu based system, do:

```
sudo aptitude install lua-posix
```

Note that ubuntu 18.04 has some problem with dependencies, so the lua-posix module does not work, requires posix.ctype library that is not installed (I've not resolved it yet).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following import before requiring the posix module.

```
require "luarocks.loader"
```

Worked flawlessly for me.

Thanks to [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415823/adam) for suggesting this in the post's comments.